# How do I get gold stars?

Tags: cooking-mama-4-kitchen-magic

In Cooking Mama 4: Kitchen Magic, I've noticed that sometimes after completing a recipe I get a gold star, and if I get a total of three (over time, not all at once), I get a reward (usually a custom item for either Mama to wear, or something to change the look of my kitchen).

What can I do to make sure I get all the stars? Is it related to score, somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a recipe step perfectly in less than half the time earns you a bonus star.

Doing a recipe step perfectly within the allotted time unlocks recipes and sometimes unlocks a "Let's Help" mini-game.

With this new found knowledge, go make Mama proud!

Comment: Hurray! I shall make her proud (and keep her from making her scary burning eyes at me...)